# How do I create multiple folders with a batch file?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

I need to create a folder (called "visitor") in every folder of one main folder. For example, my structure is this:

```
\idontknowthename1\
\idontknowthename2\
\idontknowthename3\
\idontknowthename4\
\idontknowthename5\
```

I need this:

```
\idontknowthename1\visitor
\idontknowthename2\visitor
\idontknowthename3\visitor
\idontknowthename4\visitor
\idontknowthename5\visitor
```

Of course, there are some issues:

1. I don't know the total numbers of folders in the root folder
2. I don't know the real name of every folder
3. I can't use any software or install anything more that comes with Windows XP (it's for a web server on staging and production)

I was thinking of doing this with a batch file (using `for`), but I can't work out how to get the names of the folders without parsing a file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all folders into a file:

```
dir /ad /b /s > dirlist.txt
```

For every directory, run `mkdir`:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (dirlist.txt) do mkdir "%%~a\visitor"
```

Delete temporary file:

```
del dirlist.txt
```

(It's possible to use `dir...` directly inside the `for` loop, but there is a risk of endless recursion.)

Comment: its works! thanks! But the way, it creates a visitor folder on root folder because ./ but is great. Thanks a lot, you solve me 3 days of typing (no joke)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work with folder names that have spaces.

```
@echo off

set root_folder=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%root_folder%" /ad /b') do @if not exist "%%~fa\visitor" md "%%~fa\visitor"

set root_folder=
```

You can make visitor folders in subfolders as well by adding `/s` to the `DIR` command, that is `dir "%root_folder%" /ad /b /s`.  This does not seem to suffer any issues with recursion.

Comment: hi! thanks, how can you do it with folders with blank spaces?

Comment: I updated it to include the tokens=* part and some quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

`for` has a `/d` parameter that will list the directories instead of the files.

`for /d %%i in (C:\Path\To\Root\*) do @md "%%i\visitor"`  should do the trick